# Scale.set changes size of children as well as the node it's applied to

Tags: inheritance, three.js, scale

I want to change the size of a node in a three.js scene graph. I use `scale.set()` to do that, but when I do, the size of the child nodes that have been added to the specified node are scaled also. Is there a way to scale just one node, without scaling its children too?

Answer (score 0):

Threejs (as many of the openGl APIs, frameworks or game engines) uses the [scene graph](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177194-What-is-a-scene-graph) approach, in short this means the scene is the root node and the rest of objects get created in a hierarchical way being added to the scene or to an existing object. It is an advantage to create one object with childs that will scale/rotate/move together avoiding further and more complex calculations.

If you want to scale just the parent, you have basically two ways:

- **Dirty way**: Scale on the opposite way its childs once the parent has been scaled.
- **Clean way**: Change the way you organize this object, make this parent-child relationship really sense?